# How to extract json object array to html

Tags: php, json

I have json file which mixed with json object and array. Here is the Json output  http://360workspace.com/json.php

Here is multidimensional Array output http://360workspace.com/array.php

I want to convert json or array data to html format using PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's only one way - do `foreach` and use html tags.

Comment: decode JSON and concatenate it inside HTML tags - that's how you do it.

Comment: Can you post what you've done?